# How to filter REST control based on dojo grid selection?

Tags: dojo, xpages

On an Xpage I have two REST controls that populate two enhanced dojo data grids.  One is populated with companies, the other I would like populated with the contacts of the selected company.  I am able to select a company and display the UNID of that document in a field on the xpage.  I am having difficulty filtering the contact grid based on that UNID.  What is the best way to do that?  Below is what I have tried

Populate the ParentID field with the selected doc UNID using (CSJS):

```
var grid = arguments[0].grid;
var index = arguments[0].rowIndex;
var item = grid.getItem(index).attributes;
XSP.getElementById("#{id:ParentID}").innerHTML = item.companyLink;
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:contactListPanel}")
```

Retrieve the UNID from Parent ID and use in the keys parameter of the contact REST control using (SSJS):

```
getComponent("ParentID").getValue()
```

It looks like the contact grid is refreshing when a company doc is selected, however all the contacts for all companies appear in the contact grid no matter what company is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, ParentID field doesn't get submitted to server and isn't available as parameter for REST service.

Transfer company's UNID as parameter in partialRefreshGet() instead

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:contactListPanel}", 
                      {params: {'unidCompany': item.companyLink}})
```

Read the parameter on server side with

```
param.unidCompany
```

and use it as parameter for REST service.

Comment: thank you for the reply,  I added the parameter to the partialRefresh and the param.unidCompany to the Keys parameter on the REST control, I still got all the contacts for all companies,  I tried using the categoryfilter parameter in a categories view instead and then I did not get any contacts.   Not sure why this does not work, I am running this in the Notes client (XPiNC)

Comment: Is the view categorized by companies' UNID = view's first sorted column contains company's UNID?

Comment: Yes, the view is sorted ascending by the parent id @text($REF), the contact documents are children of the company document.  If I hard code the doc id into the REST service example:  return "2CC0412A766156617625749B006BB8FD", that forces the contacts for that company to appear.  Using a parameter with the actual selected unid does not.

Comment: What does the extended Keys code  `print('param.unidCompany: ' + param.unidCompany); return param.unidCompany` show in server console?

Comment: the trace (Help, support, show trace) shows:   param.unidCompany: null